# MySQL count frequency of words

Tags: mysql, word-frequency

I want to be able to count the frequency of words occurring for a specific column.

This code works if I want to count the frequency of matching sentences, but I need it to search down into the individual word.

```
SELECT DISTINCT `Text`, COUNT(*) AS num 
FROM MyTable 
GROUP BY `Text` 
ORDER BY num DESC
```

Comment: are you trying to do it just in mysql

Comment: yep, although can use php if needed

Comment: You don't need the `DISTINCT` in there btw; `GROUP BY` already takes care of that.

Comment: you can use php and coun the words in each of thye text string you retrive

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it in code could be to read each string, for each string, tokenize by " " or some other delimiter if possible and maintain a hashtable or hashmap with each token as the key and the number of times it appears in the table as the value.

Comment: did you find a solution for your problem? How did you handle it?